# How to write multiple if condition in query statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I trying to some calculation in sql query but getting syntax error.

```
select *, 
(if( balance_advance_payment>0 ) EightBktTot = EightBktTot - balance_advance_payment    balance_advance_payment = balance_advance_payment - EightBktTot     
if( EightBktTot<0 )     (       EightBktTot=0   ) ) (if( balance_advance_payment>0 )    SevenBktTot = SevenBktTot - balance_advance_payment     balance_advance_payment = balance_advance_payment - SevenBktTot     
if( SevenBktTot<0 )     (       SevenBktTot=0   ) ) (if( balance_advance_payment>0 )    SixBktTot = SixBktTot - balance_advance_payment     balance_advance_payment = balance_advance_payment - SixBktTot   
if( SixBktTot<0 )   (       SixBktTot=0     ) ) (if( balance_advance_payment>0 )    FiveBktTot = FiveBktTot - balance_advance_payment   balance_advance_payment = balance_advance_payment - FiveBktTot  
if( FiveBktTot<0 )  ( ) (EightBktTot + SevenBktTot + (SixBktTot/2) + (FiveBktTot/2)) as bed_dept_cal  from trn_details;
```

Comment: You need to have THEN along with the IF statement. Check the mysql documentation

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense.  Do you know what `EightBktTot=0 ` does?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use CASE..WHEN inside SELECT instead of IF..THEN. That way, it will become a nested CASE..WHEN scenario for multiple IF conditions that you have.

I would also suggest to do the heavy calculation first, dump the value in a variable and then go for a simple SELECT query. This would improve code readabilty.